# Change numbers in a row from a big dataframe based on other numbers in R

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I have a big dataframe with several rows and columns and I want to change the values of a particular column.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
df1=data.frame(LOCAT=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),START=c(120,345,765,1045,1347,1879,2010,2130,2400,2560),END=c(150,390,802,1120,1436,1935,2070,2207,2476,2643),CODE1=c(1,1,0,1,0,0,-1,-1,0,-1))

> df1
   LOCAT START  END CODE1
1      1   120  150     1
2      2   345  390     1
3      3   765  802     0
4      4  1045 1120     1
5      5  1347 1436     0
6      6  1879 1935     0
7      7  2010 2070    -1
8      8  2130 2207    -1
9      9  2400 2476     0
10    10  2560 2643    -1
```

I want all the "0" of the column CODE1 which have a consecutive length of 1 to become the number immediately before. In other words, if i = 0 & i+1 !=0 & i-1 !=0, i = i-1.

I tried several formulas but they all take enormous amount of time.
This is something I tried:

```
fun = function (a)
{
for (i in 2:(length(row.names(a))-1))
{
a[a[i,4]==0 & !a[i+1,4]==0 & !a[i-1,4]==0,] <- a[i-1,4]
}
return(a)
}
```

With no success. I also thought about using the rle function to extract the 0 with length 0 from the dataframe but I simply don't know how to do it. When applying rle to my dataframe this is a short version of what I got back:

```
> table(rle1)
       values
lengths  -1  -2   0   1   2
  1      20   1 278   5   0
  2      25  18   5  15   2
  3      24   5   4  14   0
  4      20   4   2   5   0
  5      15   4   0  10   1
  6      17   1   1   3   0
  7      13   1   0   5   0
  8      12   1   0   6   0
  9       8   0   0   7   0
  10      3   1   1   4   0
```

Basically, those 278 "0" with length 1, should disappear and be another number (-1,-2,1 or 2).

This is how the example should look like:

```
> df2
   LOCAT START  END CODE1
1      1   120  150     1
2      2   345  390     1
3      3   765  802     1
4      4  1045 1120     1
5      5  1347 1436     0
6      6  1879 1935     0
7      7  2010 2070    -1
8      8  2130 2207    -1
9      9  2400 2476    -1
10    10  2560 2643    -1
```

I hope I was specific enough and anyone can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another approach that is likely to be fast. I've added comments to give an indication of what each line is doing:

```
within(df1, {
  # Where are the zeroes
  x <- which(CODE1 == 0)
  # Which of these don't have 0 in the previous or subsequent position
  x <- x[CODE1[x-1] != 0 & CODE1[x+1] != 0]
  # Replace CODE1 at this position with the value from the previous position
  CODE1[x] <- CODE1[x-1]
  # Remove the "x" value we created earlier
  rm(x)
})
#    LOCAT START  END CODE1
# 1      1   120  150     1
# 2      2   345  390     1
# 3      3   765  802     1
# 4      4  1045 1120     1
# 5      5  1347 1436     0
# 6      6  1879 1935     0
# 7      7  2010 2070    -1
# 8      8  2130 2207    -1
# 9      9  2400 2476    -1
# 10    10  2560 2643    -1
```

---

#### Whee! Benchmarks!

Here are some benchmarks after creating a much larger version of your sample `data.frame`:

```
df2 <- do.call(rbind, replicate(10000, df1, simplify=FALSE))

fun <- function (a) {
  for (i in 2:(nrow(a)-1)) {
    if(a[i,4]==0 & !a[i+1,4]==0 & !a[i-1,4]==0) {
      a[i,4] <- a[i-1,4]
    }
  }
  return(a)
}
system.time(fun(df2))
#    user  system elapsed 
# 354.448   0.322 358.397
```

^^ Ouch. Yawn. Had time to go and get a coffee with that one....

```
fun1 <- function() {
  within(df2, {
    x <- which(CODE1 == 0)
    x <- x[CODE1[x-1] != 0 & CODE1[x+1] != 0]
    CODE1[x] <- CODE1[x+1]
    rm(x)
  })
} 

fun2 <- function() {
  code_1_behind <- c(0, df2$CODE1[-nrow(df2)])
  code_1_ahead  <- c(df2$CODE1[-1], 0)
  df2$CODE1 <- ifelse(code_1_behind != 0 & code_1_ahead != 0, 
                      code_1_behind, df2$CODE1)
  df2
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(fun1(), fun2())
# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr      min       lq    median        uq      max neval
#  fun1() 16.78632 20.10185  74.80807  77.80418 128.7349   100
#  fun2() 59.36418 61.18353 114.74406 118.16778 167.3283   100
```

^^ Very close. `fun2()` doesn't seem to be quite right, but it seems (based on your comment under the answer) that you are aware of that and were able to fix it.

Comment: Thank you Ananda.
Indeed the first function was something similar to what i tried before and it does take ages. You made a replicate of 10000*10 when actually my data.frame has close to a million rows. You can imagine the amount of time that would take me.
I did fix the `fun2()` function to suit me and yours looks incredibly simple. I will add your valuable answer as the main answer as you made a really nice overview of all of the answers. Might help someone else. Thank you again, cheers

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
df1 <- data.frame(LOCAT=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                  START=c(120,345,765,1045,1347,1879,2010,2130,2400,2560),
                  END=c(150,390,802,1120,1436,1935,2070,2207,2476,2643),
                  CODE1=c(1,1,0,1,0,0,-1,-1,0,-1))

code_1_behind <- c(0, df1$CODE1[-nrow(df1)])
code_1_ahead  <- c(df1$CODE1[-1], 0)

ifelse(code_1_behind != 0 & code_1_ahead != 0, code_1_behind, df1$CODE1)
```

Comment: Brilliant!
So quick and easy. It took me a while to understand the rationale behind your solution but it fits me perfectly. I just have to change my column CODE1 with the new values that come from the last line of your solution. Well done and thank you again!

Comment: No problem.  I kind of answered in a hurry this morning, so I recognize the answer was not complete, but I'm glad it served the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
fun = function (a) {
    for (i in 2:(nrow(a)-1)) {
        if(a[i,4]==0 & !a[i+1,4]==0 & !a[i-1,4]==0) {
            a[i,4] <- a[i-1,4]
        }
    }
    return(a)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. 
The formula you wrote is pretty much the same I have and as I expected it takes ages to finish computing. The answer of JAponte worked within seconds.
Thanks again, cheers

Comment: @user2992593, I've edited [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21313061/1270695) with some benchmarks on this.